# Como comparar dois campos (estoque e minimo) da mesma Tabela em (MySql) usando C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Agradeço desde dejá,

Usando Visual Studio e MySQL:
Preciso exibir na minha GRID uma lista de produtos que apenas onde o campo 'estoque' for menor que o campo 'minimo' da minha Tabela 'produtos'.

Já consigo colocando o valor direto na linha (ex.: valor 15)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(**"@estoque", 15**);

vejam q declaro o valor 15. Mas tenho um campo onde ao cadastrar o ITEM eu determino qual será o valor mínimo.

sejam trecho do código:

//minha grid é listada assim:

private void Listar()
{

```
            con.AbrirConexao();
        
            sql = "SELECT pro.id, pro.cod, pro.nome, pro.descricao, pro.estoque, forn.nome, pro.entrada, pro.total_compra, pro.valor_compra, pro.valor_venda, pro.data, pro.imagem, pro.fornecedor, pro.minimo, pro.nota  FROM produtos as pro INNER JOIN fornecedores as forn  ON pro.fornecedor = forn.id WHERE **estoque < @estoque** ORDER BY pro.nome asc"; 

            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con.con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("**@estoque", 15**);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            grid.DataSource = dt;
            con.FecharConexao();
            FormatarGD();
        }
```

//Como faço pra ao invés de colocar o valor 15 fixo no código, buscar do campo 'minimo' da mesma tabela 'produtos' ?

Comment: Basta passar uma variável no lugar do número :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Faça um novo select utilizando a função MIN() do mysql.

Cria um parâmetro novo e executa assim:

```
sqlPrecoMinimo = "SELECT MIN(preco) FROM produtos";
```

E coloca ele no lugar do 15, exemplo:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("**@estoque", sqlPrecoMinimo**);
```

Comment: Cara, isso não é uma resposta para a pergunta do colega.
Ele não precisa nem de parâmetro, o valor de comparação esta na própria query que é o minimo, isso aqui resolveria: `SELECT pro.id, pro.cod, pro.nome, pro.descricao, pro.estoque, forn.nome, pro.entrada, pro.total_compra, pro.valor_compra, pro.valor_venda, pro.data, pro.imagem, pro.fornecedor, pro.minimo, pro.nota  FROM produtos as pro INNER JOIN fornecedores as forn  ON pro.fornecedor = forn.id WHERE estoque < pro.minimo ORDER BY pro.nome asc`

Comment: @RobertodeCampos , usei a opção 'WHERE estoque < pro.minimo' e deu super certo!!!! show me ajudou muito, meu muito obrigado pela atenção.... ainda vou tentar as opções dos outros colegas pra efeito de estudo mesmo.